# How can I get apex class parent through API?

Tags: apex, api, java

Is there any way to get parent class ( I mean inheritance, not interface) of an apex class using any  API in java?
And the same question about class modifiers (like public abstract)  - is there any way to get in through any API ?

Comment: Liudmila, what type of parent do you mean, inheritance/interface parent classes ? Which API ?    Understand that putting more effort and detail into questions will help us answer you.

Comment: Assuming you mean inheritance/interfaces, you can extract this information from the Symbol Table for the class using the Tooling API. It's not pretty (unless it's changed since I last used it) but it works.

Comment: I mean parent class, not interface. I know about Sybmol Table, it allows to extract only interfaces.  Which API - it doesn't matter, I just need to get a name of a parent class.

Comment: By parsing the body you can get the class of the classes/interfaces a class inherits/implements... I told you it wasn't pretty, but it is possible.

Comment: Sorry I didn't  get that you meant parsing body. Actually I was going to do that, but I hoped the other ways existed. But it seems that it's the only way.